# getting a js file for one page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

```
wp_register_script('SliderViewer', '/js/SliderViewer-1.2.js');
wp_enqueue_script('SliderViewer');

get_header();
```

however, `mydomain.com/js/SliderViewer-1.2.js` doesn't exist.

My js is in the ftp at

```
thewebsite -> wp-content -> themes -> BLANK-Theme -> js
```

What's the path of that? Thanks-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're registering/enqueueing your script wrong.  You should register/enqueue in your theme's `functions.php` file instead of inside the header/page.

Also, you need to use your theme's directory ... which will be along the lines of `mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/js/SliderViewer-1.2.js`.

Use this code in `functions.php`:

```
function my_scripts_enqueue_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'SliderViewer',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/SliderViewer-1.2.js'
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue_method' );
```

This will enqueue *and* register your script, and ensure that you're using the appropriate directory for your theme in the process.

Comment: I'm just trying to do this for ONE page though.

Comment: For *one* page, then, you should really be using a custom page template. But the guidance on referencing the script in your call to `wp_enqueue_script()` stands.

Comment: This all works (accepted), but now I'm curious.. What was the problem with using `wp_register_script`? I like to be enlightened.

Comment: No problem, just unnecessary.  `wp_enqueue_script()` will automatically register the script for you. The biggest change was using `get_template_directory_uri()` to build the path to your script.

Comment: but you register with this snippet on all pages, backend and frontend. Use Conditional Tags, like `is_admin()` and `is_singular()` to load only on page, there you will use this script.

Comment: If you register the script first, then, (**since 3.3**) you can use `wp_enqueue_script()` inside templates (or inside shortcode callbacks) and the script is loaded in the footer (if the theme behaves...). Then you can load the script only when its needed (for a particular template, shortcode etc)